# React Swiper Navigation not working how to work it?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

Working on Swiper react component.
But navigation or anything others are not working.

https://swiperjs.com/react

```
        <Swiper
          // install Swiper modules
          modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
          spaceBetween={50}
          slidesPerView={1}
          navigation={true}
          pagination={{ clickable: true }}
          className="mySwiper"
        >
        {banners.map((item, i) => (
          <SwiperSlide>
            <div className="slider-single">
              blabla
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
```

Here's my code above.
Navigation arrows are appering. But when I click on them, It doesnt move to next slide. (It moves to next when I drag it)

Answer (score 5):

Hard to answer your Q (Without full code example).

#### Did you install Navigation module (Y/N)?

The best idea is to compare your code to this official demo:

**Swiper Navigation demo - codesandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/13eu6

From the docs:

> By default Swiper React uses core version of Swiper (without any
> additional modules). If you want to use **Navigation**, Pagination and
> other modules, **you have to install them first**.

```
// import Swiper core and required modules
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper';

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';

export default () => {
  return (
    <Swiper
      // install Swiper modules
      modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      navigation
      pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      ...
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```

Comment: but how to  install navigation apart from swiper?

Comment: Use import and the name of the module // core navigation module:
  import Swiper, { Navigation } from 'swiper';. More correct to say "import and configure"

Answer (score 2):

I will like to answer a few questions in the mind of some people.

> By default Swiper React uses core version of Swiper (without any
> additional modules). If you want to use Navigation, Pagination and
> other modules, you have to install them first.

The extract above is from the official documentation https://swiperjs.com/react. However, the last part says 'you have to install them first', this is not asking you to do npm install of anything again.

All that is required are 2.

1. import SwiperCore and any other module you want to use from "swiper" or "swiper/modules"

```js
// import Swiper core and required modules
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from "swiper";
```

2. Install or register the imported modules as demonstrated in code snippet below

```js
// Install Swiper modules
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination]);
```

Comment: You can also style the navigation buttons to your taste by tageting their classnames e.g. .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';
```

As Ezra Siton said, i think the problem is import styles commands missing.

Answer (score 0):

super simple

in your component

```
 <Swiper
  // install Swiper modules
  modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
  ...
  **navigation ={true}**
 ... other configs
>
```

Or you could instantiate a custom Build like so:

// Import Swiper and modules

```
import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar } from 'swiper';

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  // Install modules
  modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar],
  speed: 500,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  // ...
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the bundled css file.

```
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css";
```

Answer (score -1):

**2023 Answer** 
You have to import Navigation module from `swiper/modules`

Import:

```js
// other import statements 
import { Navigation } from 'swiper/modules'
import 'swiper/css/navigation'
```

Render

```
<Swiper
    navigation
    modules={[Navigation]}
    // rest of your props 
/>
```